# How to hide single div based on selected option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make sure the second dropdown menu only starts showing when an option ("Tijd" or "Woorden") is selected in the first one. When no option is selected afterwards, the second dropdown has to hide again.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <p>Spelmodus:</p>
    <select id="spelmodus" name="spelmodus" onchange="changeSpelmodus(this.value);">
      <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="optieDiv">
    <p id="tijdWoorden"></p>
    <select id="opties" name="opties" onchange="changeOptie(this.value);">
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var spelmodusOpties = {
        "Tijd": [{"Optie": "1 minuut"}, {"Optie": "2 minuten"}, {"Optie": "5 minuten"}],
        "Woorden": [{"Optie": "50 woorden"}, {"Optie": "100 woorden"}, {"Optie": "150 woorden"}],
    };
    
    function PrepopulateSpelmodus() {
      var spelmodusSelect = document.getElementById('spelmodus');
      var i = 1;
      for (var spelmodus in spelmodusOpties) {
        spelmodusSelect.options[i++] = new Option(spelmodus)
      }
    
    }
    
    function changeSpelmodus(productNameID) {
      var optieSelect = document.getElementById('opties');
      optieSelect.innerHTML = '<option></option>'; // Remove previous options
      var versions = spelmodusOpties[productNameID];
      for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
        optieSelect.appendChild(new Option(versions[i].Optie));
      }
    
      var selectie = document.getElementById('spelmodus').value;
      document.getElementById('tijdWoorden').innerHTML = selectie
    
    }
    
    function changeOptie() {
      var productNameID = document.getElementById('spelmodus').value;
      var versions = spelmodusOpties[productNameID];
      for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
      }
    }
    
    PrepopulateSpelmodus();
```

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to validate and hide on change of select

```
if(!productNameID){
   document.getElementById('optieDiv').style.display = "none"
   return;
}else{
   document.getElementById('optieDiv').style.display = ""
}
```

```js
 var spelmodusOpties = {
        "Tijd": [{"Optie": "1 minuut"}, {"Optie": "2 minuten"}, {"Optie": "5 minuten"}],
        "Woorden": [{"Optie": "50 woorden"}, {"Optie": "100 woorden"}, {"Optie": "150 woorden"}],
    };
    
    function PrepopulateSpelmodus() {
      var spelmodusSelect = document.getElementById('spelmodus');
      var i = 1;
      for (var spelmodus in spelmodusOpties) {
        spelmodusSelect.options[i++] = new Option(spelmodus)
      }
    
    }
    
    function changeSpelmodus(productNameID) {
      if(!productNameID){
      document.getElementById('optieDiv').style.display = "none"
      return;
      }else{
      document.getElementById('optieDiv').style.display = ""
      }
      var optieSelect = document.getElementById('opties');
      optieSelect.innerHTML = '<option></option>'; // Remove previous options
      var versions = spelmodusOpties[productNameID];
      for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
        optieSelect.appendChild(new Option(versions[i].Optie));
      }
    
      var selectie = document.getElementById('spelmodus').value;
      document.getElementById('tijdWoorden').innerHTML = selectie
    
    }
    
    function changeOptie() {
      var productNameID = document.getElementById('spelmodus').value;
      var versions = spelmodusOpties[productNameID];
      for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
      }
    }
    
    PrepopulateSpelmodus();
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <p>Spelmodus:</p>
    <select id="spelmodus" name="spelmodus" onchange="changeSpelmodus(this.value);">
      <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="optieDiv" style="display: none">
    <p id="tijdWoorden"></p>
    <select id="opties" name="opties" onchange="changeOptie(this.value);">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: In the first code snippet, there's no need for an `else` block if you `return` in its corresponding `if` block

Comment: I know @Tom. I have added for easy to understand for New Developers

Comment: That is a personal preference then. I think less code is easier for any developer to read, but again not really a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const optieDivEl = document.querySelector('#optieDiv');

function toggleOptieDiv(event) {
  // Check if the event.target (select) is one of the specified values
  if (['tijd', 'woorden'].includes(event.target.value)) {
    // Do no render `div.optieDiv` 
    optieDivEl.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    // Render `div.optieDiv`
    optieDivEl.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
document.onload = toggleOptieDiv;
document.querySelector('#spelmodus').addEventListener('change', toggleOptieDiv);
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <p>Spelmodus:</p>
  <select id="spelmodus" name="spelmodus">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="tijd">Tijd</option>
    <option value="woorden">Woorden</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="optieDiv">
  <p id="tijdWoorden"></p>
  <select id="opties" name="opties" onchange="changeOptie(this.value);">
  </select>
</div>
```